Internal Image in RSS
I have a content channel on my wordpress website that is shared with another website. However, when submitting a post with text and a featured image, along with internal photos, the target site is only displaying the text and featured image, failing to show the other images present in the post.
I'm a beginner in using wordpress and I'm having difficulty finding the correct place to edit or customize the Feed/RSS, including adding codes to import the internal images. The RSS link is available, but I don't know how to proceed.
Is there anyone who can help me or is there a plugin that can do the job?
